# I am not getting the expected output

Tags: c

Every week the number of unique visitors grows with 7% compared to the previous week.

Giving an integer number N representing the number of unique visitors at the end of this week and an integer number W

### Your task is to:

Write a function that prints to the standard output (stdout) the number of unique visitors we are going to have after W weeks

Please round the final result downwards to the nearest integer (e.g both 7.1 and 7.9 are rounded to 7)

### Note that your function will receive the following arguments:

- `n`: which is an integer representing the number N described above
- `w`: which is an integer representing the number W described above

### Data constraints:

- The value for `n` will not exceed 10000
- The value for `w` will not exceed 50

### Sample Input And Output:

1. n=10, w=3

   Answer:12
2. n=40, w=1

   Answer:42

What I have Tried are as follows:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include"math.h"

void compute_prediction(int n, int w)
{
    //Percentage Calculation
    if(n<100001 && w<51)   
    {  
        double percent= 0.07*n;
        // After 'W' weeks
        double wcalc=(percent*w);
        printf("%d",((int)floor(wcalc))+n);
    } 
}
```

Given Input: n=100,  w=4 my output is: 128. But the Correct Output is 131.

Comment: `But Correct Output is 131.` how you calculate it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding [math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest).

Comment: is this your homework?

Comment: Also you have give sample input and output. have you not doubt in that? why on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this program during calculation ,you are taking 100 fixed visitors every week which is wrong.

The correct way to do that is:

```
1st week=100/100*7+100=107
2nd week=7/100*107+107=114
3rd  week=7/100*114+114=122
4th week=(.07)*122+122=131
```

You will get the output as 131.

Comment: Oh I understood the mistake.. Very Good Explanation Bro... Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You should use [geometric series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) formula: u(n) = u(0) * q^n
In your case, it's wcalc = n * 0.07^w

In code (we need to include math header for pow function):

```
#include <math.h>

void compute_prediction(int n, int w)   {
    if(n > 100000 || w > 50)
        return;
    double wcalc = n * pow(1.07, w);
    // No need to use floor, a cast is enough
    printf("%ld", (long)wcalc);
}
```